# Maybe after Completable in chain

Tags: rx-java, chain

How can I create a chain right way in next case?
Now I have:

```
someSingle()
.filter{...}
.flatMapSingleElement { Single.create {...} }
.doOnError(...)
.onErrorReturnItem(...)
.switchIfEmpty(...)
```

But I need to paste anotherSingle() and someCompletable() after someSingle() in chain and don't break this chain. So I try the next:

```
someSingle()
.filter{...}
.flatMapSingle { anotherSingle() }
.flatMapCompletable { someCompletable() }
```

and what I can do next to continue the chain with

```
.flatMapSingleElement { Single.create {...} }
.doOnError(...)
.onErrorReturnItem(...)
.switchIfEmpty(...)
```

?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `andThen` operator.

```
 someSingle()
.filter{...}
.flatMapSingle { anotherSingle() }
.flatMapCompletable { someCompletable() }
.andThen(Maybe.just())
```

or as an example

```
  Single.just("Hello")
        .flatMapCompletable {
            Completable.complete()
        }
        .andThen(Maybe.just("Maybe"))
        .subscribe {
            println("Result $it")
        }
```